# How to disable default logging in logback.xml

Tags: xml, logging, logback

I have one query about logback.xml, how to disable default_engine_log which is genrated by logback.xml file.
Because we are create another file using logback.xml for LOGGING LEVEL. So there is no need for default_engine_log log file.

here my code is--

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">

  <appender name="RootFileAppender" 
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <append>true</append>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>info</level>
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>fom-logs/fom-deshboard-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [LogBack %level] %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>  
  <appender name="RootConsoleAppender" 
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>info</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>[LogBack %level] %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>  
  <root>
    <level value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RootFileAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RootConsoleAppender"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

`

Comment: What default log? Can you show some output from it?

Comment: As per the code we are using log level for logging and create logging file in given path "<fileNamePattern>fom-logs/fom-deshboard-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>"
But by default its create default-engine-log file also which is genrated in logs folder, Now we are getting two logs file which is not required.
We want only fom-logs folder and disable default-engine-log file